# How to detect Swiping UP, DOWN, LEFT and RIGHT with SwiftUI on a View

Tags: swiftui, swipe, apple-watch

I'm getting into building Apple Watch apps.

What I'm currently working on will require me to make use of detecting swipes in the four main directions (`UP`, `DOWN`, `LEFT` and `RIGHT`)

The problem is I have no idea how to detect this. I've been looking around and I'm reaching dead ends.

What can I do to my view below to just print `swiped up` when the user swipes `UP` on the view?

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Based on Benjamin's answer this is a *swiftier* way to handle the cases

```
.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 3.0, coordinateSpace: .local)
    .onEnded { value in
        print(value.translation)
        switch(value.translation.width, value.translation.height) {
            case (...0, -30...30):  print("left swipe")
            case (0..., -30...30):  print("right swipe")
            case (-100...100, ...0):  print("up swipe")
            case (-100...100, 0...):  print("down swipe")
            default:  print("no clue")
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 80):

You could use `DragGesture`

```
.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                    .onEnded({ value in
                        if value.translation.width < 0 {
                            // left
                        }

                        if value.translation.width > 0 {
                            // right
                        }
                        if value.translation.height < 0 {
                            // up
                        }

                        if value.translation.height > 0 {
                            // down
                        }
                    }))
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot! Thank you :) It looks like it's just what I need!

Comment: This looks good, but doesn't work correctly.  Unless you are a robot is is almost impossible not to generate multiple responses.

Comment: if you need that your scroll view should work then minimumDistance distance should be grater than zero.

Answer (score 60):

With the other solutions being a bit inconsistent on a physical device, I decided to come up with another one that seems to be much more consistent across different screen sizes as there are no hardcoded values except for the `minimumDistance`.

```
.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 20, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onEnded { value in
                let horizontalAmount = value.translation.width
                let verticalAmount = value.translation.height
                
                if abs(horizontalAmount) > abs(verticalAmount) {
                    print(horizontalAmount < 0 ? "left swipe" : "right swipe")
                } else {
                    print(verticalAmount < 0 ? "up swipe" : "down swipe")
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 33):

If you want one that is more "forgiving" to the directionality of the swipe, you can use a few more conditionals to help even it out:

EDIT: did some more testing, apparently the values for the second conditional add some confusion, so I adjusted them to remove said confusion and make the gesture bulletproof (drags to the corners will now come up with "no clue" instead of one of the gestures)...

```js
let detectDirectionalDrags = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 3.0, coordinateSpace: .local)
.onEnded { value in
    print(value.translation)
    
    if value.translation.width < 0 && value.translation.height > -30 && value.translation.height < 30 {
        print("left swipe")
    }
    else if value.translation.width > 0 && value.translation.height > -30 && value.translation.height < 30 {
        print("right swipe")
    }
    else if value.translation.height < 0 && value.translation.width < 100 && value.translation.width > -100 {
        print("up swipe")
    }
    else if value.translation.height > 0 && value.translation.width < 100 && value.translation.width > -100 {
        print("down swipe")
    }
    else {
        print("no clue")
    }
```

Comment: Where should one put this variable in their view?

Comment: @soylentgraham put this in the struct between the var body: some View { and the return...by default, swiftUI (if you don't have a return statement in this section) will return the first swiftui element (first ZStack/HStack/etc), but if you put "return" before your first swiftui element, you can add variables that would normally give you an error if added before the var body some view...

Comment: I'm shocked that defining behavior like this requires what seems to be very explicit construction, and error-prone construction. Does the swiping "feel nice" on both landscape and portrait orientations? This seems like a big hole in the API.

Comment: What are the best translation widths/heights for swiping left, right, up and down and how to make that "relative" to the device size (compact/regular) used? Here fixed with 30/100 but is this the same Apple uses for their apps?

Comment: I just want to echo the question that @JeanNicolas asked above.  Apple's documentation offers no help in determining what the number 30 or 100 in the presented solutions really means - or what these values should be to gain useful functionality across all Apple devices.

Answer (score 9):

Create an extension:

```swift
extension View {
    func swipe(
        up: @escaping (() -> Void) = {},
        down: @escaping (() -> Void) = {},
        left: @escaping (() -> Void) = {},
        right: @escaping (() -> Void) = {}
    ) -> some View {
        return self.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onEnded({ value in
                if value.translation.width < 0 { left() }
                if value.translation.width > 0 { right() }
                if value.translation.height < 0 { up() }
                if value.translation.height > 0 { down() }
            }))
    }
}
```

Then:

```swift
            Image() // or any View
                .swipe(
                    up: {
                        // action for up
                    },
                    right: {
                        // action for right
                    })
```

Notice that each direction is an optional parameter

Answer (score 5):

This is much more responsive:

```
.gesture(
    DragGesture()
        .onEnded { value in
            
            let pi = Double.pi
            
            let direction = atan2(value.translation.width, value.translation.height)
            
            switch direction {
            case (-pi/4..<pi/4): print("down swipe")
            case (pi/4..<pi*3/4): print("right swipe")
            case (pi*3/4...pi), (-pi..<(-pi*3/4)):
                print("up swipe")
            case (-pi*3/4..<(-pi/4)): print("left swipe")
            default:
                print("no clue")
            }
        }
```

Explanation:

- Drag gesture returns a vector of change as `value.translation`
- This method then uses [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) to find the direction of that vector as follows

Based on how `value.translation` is returned, the values of `atan2` will be as follows:

- `π` would match an ideal "up" gesture
- `-π/2` is an ideal "left" gesture
- `0.0` would match an ideal "down" gesture
- `π/2` is an ideal "right" gesture

So now we want to split the circle into 4 quarters, with each quarter including each value above in the middle. For instance `(-π/4...π/4)` would include any value that could be considered an approximation of a "down" direction.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

I would create a modifier for simplicity. Usage will look like that:

```
yourView
        .onSwiped(.down) {
            // Action for down swipe
        }
```

OR

```
yourView
        .onSwiped { direction in 
            // React to detected swipe direction
        }
```

You can also use `trigger` parameter in order to configure receiving updates: continuously or only when the gesture ends.

## Here's the full code:

```
struct SwipeModifier: ViewModifier {
    enum Directions: Int {
        case up, down, left, right
    }

    enum Trigger {
        case onChanged, onEnded
    }

    var trigger: Trigger
    var handler: ((Directions) -> Void)?

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.gesture(
            DragGesture(
                minimumDistance: 24,
                coordinateSpace: .local
            )
            .onChanged {
                if trigger == .onChanged {
                    handle($0)
                }
            }.onEnded {
                if trigger == .onEnded {
                    handle($0)
                }
            }
        )
    }

    private func handle(_ value: _ChangedGesture<DragGesture>.Value) {
        let hDelta = value.translation.width
        let vDelta = value.translation.height

        if abs(hDelta) > abs(vDelta) {
            handler?(hDelta < 0 ? .left : .right)
        } else {
            handler?(vDelta < 0 ? .up : .down)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func onSwiped(
        trigger: SwipeModifier.Trigger = .onChanged,
        action: @escaping (SwipeModifier.Directions) -> Void
    ) -> some View {
        let swipeModifier = SwipeModifier(trigger: trigger) {
            action($0)
        }
        return self.modifier(swipeModifier)
    }
    func onSwiped(
        _ direction: SwipeModifier.Directions,
        trigger: SwipeModifier.Trigger = .onChanged,
        action: @escaping () -> Void
    ) -> some View {
        let swipeModifier = SwipeModifier(trigger: trigger) {
            if direction == $0 {
                action()
            }
        }
        return self.modifier(swipeModifier)
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working in the TabView only. Is any way so it can work in every view?

Answer (score 2):

Little bit late to this, but here's another implementation which uses OptionSet to make its use a bit more like various other SwiftUI components -

```
struct Swipe: OptionSet, Equatable {
    
    init(rawValue: Int) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }
    
    let rawValue: Int
    
    fileprivate var swiped: ((DragGesture.Value, Double) -> Bool) = { _, _ in false } // prevents a crash if someone creates a swipe directly using the init
    
    private static let sensitivityFactor: Double = 400 // a fairly arbitrary figure which gives a reasonable response
    
    static var left: Swipe {
        var swipe = Swipe(rawValue: 1 << 0)
        swipe.swiped = { value, sensitivity in
            value.translation.width < 0 && value.predictedEndTranslation.width < sensitivity * sensitivityFactor
        }
        return swipe
    }

    static var right: Swipe {
        var swipe = Swipe(rawValue: 1 << 1)
        swipe.swiped = { value, sensitivity in
            value.translation.width > 0 && value.predictedEndTranslation.width > sensitivity * sensitivityFactor
        }
        return swipe
    }

    static var up: Swipe {
        var swipe = Swipe(rawValue: 1 << 2)
        swipe.swiped = { value, sensitivity in
            value.translation.height < 0 && value.predictedEndTranslation.height < sensitivity * sensitivityFactor
        }
        return swipe
    }

    static var down: Swipe {
        var swipe = Swipe(rawValue: 1 << 3)
        swipe.swiped = { value, sensitivity in
            value.translation.height > 0 && value.predictedEndTranslation.height > sensitivity * sensitivityFactor
        }
        return swipe
    }
    
    static var all: Swipe {
        [.left, .right, .up, .down]
    }
    
    private static var allCases: [Swipe] = [.left, .right, .up, .down]
    
    fileprivate var array: [Swipe] {
        Swipe.allCases.filter { self.contains($0) }
    }
}

extension View {
    
    func swipe(_ swipe: Swipe, sensitivity: Double = 1, action: @escaping (Swipe) -> ()) -> some View {
        
        return gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 30, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onEnded { value in
                swipe.array.forEach { swipe in
                    if swipe.swiped(value, sensitivity) {
                        action(swipe)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

In a SwiftUI view -

```
HStack {
    // content
}
.swipe([.left, .right]) { swipe in // could also be swipe(.left) or swipe(.all), etc
    doSomething(with: swipe)
}
```

Obviously the logic for detecting swipes is a bit basic, but that's easy enough to tailor to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwipeModifier: ViewModifier {

let rightToLeftAction: () -> ()
let leftToRightAction: () -> ()

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 20, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onEnded { value in
                let horizontalAmount = value.translation.width
                let verticalAmount = value.translation.height
                
                guard abs(horizontalAmount) > abs(verticalAmount) else {
                    return
                }
                
                withAnimation {
                    horizontalAmount < 0 ? rightToLeftAction() :  leftToRightAction()
                }
            })
    }
}

extension View {
  func swipe(rightToLeftAction: @escaping () -> (), leftToRightAction: @escaping () -> ()) -> some View {
     modifier(SwipeModifier(rightToLeftAction: rightToLeftAction, leftToRightAction: leftToRightAction))
   }
}
```

Improved version of Fynn Becker's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension to support my use case based on Fynn Becker answer.

```swift
typealias SwipeDirectionAction = (SwipeDirection) -> Void

extension View {
  /// Adds an action to perform when swipe end.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - action: The action to perform when this swipe ends.
  ///   - minimumDistance: The minimum dragging distance for the gesture to succeed.
  func onSwipe(action: @escaping SwipeDirectionAction, minimumDistance: Double = 20) -> some View {
    self
      .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: minimumDistance, coordinateSpace: .global)
        .onEnded { value in
          let horizontalAmount = value.translation.width
          let verticalAmount = value.translation.height

          if abs(horizontalAmount) > abs(verticalAmount) {
            horizontalAmount < 0 ? action(.left) : action(.right)
          } else {
            verticalAmount < 0 ? action(.up) : action(.bottom)
          }
        })
  }
}

enum SwipeDirection {
  case up, bottom, left, right
}
```

Usage:

```swift
  var body: some View {
    SpriteView(scene: scene)
      .ignoresSafeArea()
      .onSwipe { direction in
        print(direction)
      }
  }
```